# wordpress ... toggle the new comment_form

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I am trying to insert a link to toggle the comment_form using jQuery onclick, but it does not work ...

In my comments.php , I added the following html around the comment_form() :

```
      <p>BEFORE FORM</p>
      <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="jQuery('#add-comment).toggle();">Toggle comment-form</a>
      <div id="add-comment" style:"display:none;">

        <?php $comments_args = array(
        ....
        );
        comment_form($comments_args);
        ?>

      <p>AFTER FORM</p>       
      </div>
```

and to be sure jQuery is loaded, I added the following code in my functions.php

```
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
```

the link is correctly displayed but the form is not hidden and the toggle does not activate ..
where am I wrong ?

Comment: I'd advise against loading jQuery from external sources. WordPress brings its own modified jQuery which can be loaded by any plugin or theme and you'll run into problems as soon as both are loaded (or mootools or any other library that uses conflicting variables). Stick with the jQuery shipped with WordPress.

Comment: Regarding your problem: Any error messages in your browsers javascript console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

You are missing the closing quote:

```
<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="jQuery('#add-comment').toggle();">Toggle comment-form</a>
                                                       ^-- here
```

which results in a syntax error. Apart from that, you need a `=` instead of a `:`:

```
<div id="add-comment" style="display:none;">
                           ^- here
```

This is the reason why the form isn't hidden at the start.

With these two errors fixed it works:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>BEFORE FORM</p>
      <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="jQuery('#add-comment').toggle();">Toggle comment-form</a>
      <div id="add-comment" style="display:none;">

        Comment form

      <p>AFTER FORM</p>       
      </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right , I just discovered it and I was typing my response ... 
I discovered it by testing a simple alert('OK'); ...